# What are 'get' and 'set' in Swift?

Tags: swift, accessor

I'm learning Swift and I'm reading *The Swift Programming Language* from Apple. I don't have any Objective-C background (only [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), JavaScript, and others, but not Objective-C).

On page 24-25 I see this code:

```
//...Class definition stuff...

var perimeter: Double {
    get {
        return 3.0 * sideLength
    }
    set {
        sideLength = newValue / 3.0
    }
}

//...Class continues...
```

This part is *not* specified in the book, and I can't get what those are for.

What are **get** and **set**?

Comment: Did you read pg 21 about getter/setter.  Also, first 30 pgs or so are a *tour* of Swift and not the full documentation.

Comment: If you have done C++ you can co-relate this stuff with getter and setter member functions of class

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The getting and setting of variables within classes refers to either retrieving ("getting") or altering ("setting") their contents.

Consider a variable `members` of a class `family`. Naturally, this variable would need to be an integer, since a family can never consist of two point something people.

So you would probably go ahead by defining the `members` variable like this:

```
class family {
    var members: Int
}
```

This, however, will give people using this class the possibility to set the number of family members to something like 0 or 1. And since there is no such thing as a family of 1 or 0, this is quite unfortunate.

This is where the getters and setters come in. This way you can decide for yourself how variables can be altered and what values they can receive, as well as deciding what content they return.

Returning to our family class, let's make sure nobody can set the `members` value to anything less than 2:

```
class family {
    var _members: Int = 2
    var members: Int {
      get {
        return _members
      }
      set (newVal) {
        if newVal >= 2 {
          _members = newVal
        } else {
          println('error: cannot have family with less than 2 members')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can access the `members` variable as before, by typing `instanceOfFamily.members`, and thanks to the setter function, we can also set it's value as before, by typing, for example: `instanceOfFamily.members = 3`. What has changed, however, is the fact that we cannot set this variable to anything smaller than 2 anymore.

Note the introduction of the `_members` variable, which is the actual variable to store the value that we set through the `members` setter function. The original `members` has now become a computed property, meaning that it only acts as an interface to deal with our actual variable.

Comment: `members` ==> `count`, `numberOfMembers`; `var members : Set<Person>` ??

Comment: `set (newVal) { ... }`, newVal is implied, so `set { _members = newVal }` is also correct.

Comment: Note that variables like `_members` should be private, otherwise the command `instanceOfFamily._members=1` would set `instanceOfFamily.members` to a value below 2

Comment: Looks like the default parameter is named `newValue` in Swift 4 – https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID260

Answer (score 36):

A simple question should be followed by a short, simple and clear answer.

- When we are getting a value of the property it fires its `get{}` part.
- When we are setting a value to the property it fires its `set{}` part.

PS. When setting a value to the property, Swift automatically creates a constant named "newValue" = a value we are setting. After a constant "newValue" becomes accessible in the property's `set{}` part.

Example:

```
var A:Int = 0
var B:Int = 0

var C:Int {
get {return 1}
set {print("Recived new value", newValue, " and stored into 'B' ")
     B = newValue
     }
}

// When we are getting a value of C it fires get{} part of C property
A = C
A            // Now A = 1

// When we are setting a value to C it fires set{} part of C property
C = 2
B            // Now B = 2
```

Comment: is it mandatory to assign a default value for member to be accessing from outside the class.

i had this problem as fixed when i assign default value for it 


class UserBean:NSObject {

    var user_id: String? = nil 
}


accessing it like the following 

let user:UserBean = UserBean()
user.user_id =  "23232332"

Answer (score 7):

You should look at [Computed Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_322).

In your code sample, `perimeter` is a property not backed up by a class variable. Instead its value is computed using the `get` method and stored via the `set` method - usually referred to as *getter* and *setter*.

When you use that property like this:

```
var cp = myClass.perimeter
```

you are invoking the code contained in the `get` code block, and when you use it like this:

```
myClass.perimeter = 5.0
```

You are invoking the code contained in the `set` code block, where `newValue` is automatically filled with the value provided at the right of the assignment operator.

Computed properties can be read/write if both a getter and a setter are specified, or read-only if the getter only is specified.

Answer (score 5):

A variable declares and is called like this in a class:

```
class X {
    var x: Int = 3

}

var y = X()
print("value of x is: ", y.x)

//value of x is:  3
```

Now you want the program to make the default value of x more than or equal to 3. Now take the hypothetical case if x is less than 3: your program will fail.

So, you want people to either put in 3 or more than 3. Swift got it easy for you and it is important to understand this bit - it is an advanced way of dating the variable value, because they will extensively use it in iOS development. Now let's see how *get* and *set* will be used here.

```
class X {
    var _x: Int = 3
    var x: Int {
        get {
            return _x
        }
        set(newVal) {  // Set always take one argument
            if newVal >= 3 {
                _x = newVal // Updating _x with the input value by the user
                print("new value is: ", _x)
            }
            else {
                print("error must be greater than 3")
            }
        }
    }
}

let y = X()
y.x = 1
print(y.x) // The error must be greater than 3
y.x = 8 // // The new value is: 8
```

If you still have doubts, just remember the use of *get* and *set* is to update any variable the way we want it to be updated. *get* and *set* will give you better control to rule your logic. It is a powerful tool, hence not easily understandable.