# What is the difference between `get {}` and `{ get }` in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have been looking at the UIViewController class and trying to understand some of its code, namely, the `get` that is mentioned in class. I've searched on google "What does get{} mean in swift" and found the following resources: [Swift what are 'get' and 'set'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699327/swift-what-are-get-and-set) and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html, under the section, "Computer Properties". However, the `get` that is mentioned here is not what I was looking for, that is, both of these `get`s that are mentioned in these two links are in the following form:

```
var center: Point {
        get {
            let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
            let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
            return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        }
```

Note the `get {}` here. However, the `get` that I am confused with is as follows:

```
extension UIViewController {
    // These objects may be used as layout items in the NSLayoutConstraint API
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    var topLayoutGuide: UILayoutSupport { get }
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    var bottomLayoutGuide: UILayoutSupport { get }
}
```

Note the `{ get }` here.

Could anybody clarify what the distinction between the `get {}` and `{ get }`? Thank you so much for your time and effort in answering this question in advance!

Comment: you don't waste much time with documentation, do you?

Comment: Well, after the documentation comes the next step: try it out. and than, if you didn't figured it out in between, u ask. With providing all findings you got on the way.

Answer (score 6):

`?` means the variable can be null, or "optional" in Swift-speak.

`{ get }` means the property is read only. It cannot be modified.