# Why do we use the keyword "get" in Swift variables declaration?

Tags: swift, variables, getter

This might sound dumb, but I can't figure out why programmers declare variables in Swift as follows:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

Why is the keyword "get" used? Why is "set" missed? I thought we used them like this:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String {
        get {
          // getter
        }
        set {
          // setter
        }
    }
}
```

This might be a spam question, but I am interested in the theoretical definition of **{ get }**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699327/swift-what-are-get-and-set

Comment: Thanks , I know how to use **set**, **get**, **willSet**, **didSet**, but I am curious about this particular piece of code: **{ get }**. And why it doesn't actually return anything?

Comment: You should add a return statement in it. get { return name}. I guess this statement "var name: String { get }" is only to show a brief code snippet.

Comment: The syntax `var foo: String { get { return "bar" } }` (which can be shortened to `var foo: String { return "bar" }`) declares a computed property that doesn't have a setter. Your second example is a computed property with both a getter and a setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sentences such as `var name: String { get }` are normally used in protocols not in classes. In a protocol it means that the implementation must have a variable of type String which should be at least read only (hence the `get`). Had the curly brackets bit been `{ get set }` the variable would have been read write.

Actually as per Earl Grey answer, `var name: String { get }` will not compile inside a class.

Comment: Great, thanks! The confusion came from the Assistant editor, when I transformed the interface of an Obj-C class to Swift, and the editor generated this variable. Now I understand all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The first code example strictly speaking doesn't make sense. You do not declare variables like this in a class.. (You do it in a protocol like this.)

The second is an example of computed property,though the getter and setter implementation is missing. (it seems to be implied at least so I won't object about validity of the code example.)