# Swift what does the closure immediately after squared bracket wrapped array do

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization, closures

I am following the official tutorial of IOS dev from Apple. I encounter this small block and could not wrap my head around of it.

`Landmark` is the data model

```
@Published var landmarks: [Landmark]

var features: [Landmark]{
        landmarks.filter{$0.isFeatured}
    }
```

Apparently `features` is an array with `Landmark` type as its member. The `landmarks.filter{$0.isFeatured}` is simply trying to filter out those `Landmark`s that have their property `isFeatured` to be `true`.

But I've checked out the initialization of an array in Swift, those you see are like you using `var features = landmarks.filter($0.isFeatured)`. And you barely see any example of `[ something ] { something }`

Is the sample code the proper way to initialize an array with closure?

For those who interested trying out yourself, you can try the toy code below in playground:

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    var isYes: Bool
    var name: String
}

let myArray = [
    MyStruct(isYes: true, name: "A"),
    MyStruct(isYes: true, name: "B"),
    MyStruct(isYes: false, name: "C"),
]

print("hello")
print(myArray)

var myArray2: [MyStruct]{
    myArray.filter{$0.isYes}
}

print(myArray2)

//var myArray3: [MyStruct] = myArray.filter($0.isYes)
//
//print(myArray3)

//var myArray4: [MyStruct] = {myArray.filter($0.isYes)}
//
//print(myArray4)

//var myArray5<MyStruct> = {myArray.filter($0.isYes)}
//
//print(myArray5)

var arrayB = myArray.filter{$0.isYes}
print(arrayB)
```

Comment: It's the `get` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24699836/14351818)

Comment: If you only have `get` and no `set`, you can get rid of the inner `get {}` syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "initialization" in that code. You are looking at a computed variable (property).

`features` is, in effect, a *function* that returns a value (with the word `return` omitted because it is a one liner); it just runs afresh each time you say `features`.

This *could* have been written as

```
func features() -> [Landmark] {
    landmarks.filter{$0.isFeatured}
}
```

but one has a feeling that this is better expressed as a sort of property than as a method.

Here's a simpler case to play with in a playground:

```
struct Greeter {
    var greeting : String { "howdy" }
    func greet() -> String { "howdy" }
}
let greeter = Greeter()
print(greeter.greeting)
print(greeter.greet())
```

Comment: *Computed* property right?

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is very clear. So I might summarize it as: to make a property both dynamic and shorthanded, such that whenever `features` is called, it gets the most updated values based on user input.

Comment: I would say it the way I said it. It isn't "really" a property at all; it's a function that you call using property syntax.